# ternary operator in list comprehension not working as expected

Tags: python, list, operating-system, list-comprehension

EDIT: this question turns out to be not related to list comprehension at all. The problem was caused by not passing the full path but only the filename into the `os.path.isfile()` which makes it always evaluate to False.

Why does the if/else at front of this list comprehension not work as expected? The statement below produced a list with all 0 (else case).

```
[1 if os.path.isfile(file) else 0 for file in os.listdir(path)]
```

The expected output will be 1 if the file is a file, and 0 if the file is a directory
I have tested `1 if os.path.isfile(file) else 0` independently on another line and it works as expected (there are mixture of 1 and 0). I cannot find any syntax problem with my list comprehension statement.

What's more interesting is that if I replace the condition with something else, like `1 if file else 0`, the behaviour flipped. Now every item become 1 even though some is expected to be 0 (Again, I verified them independently using the exact same conditional expression)

I have tried adding `bool()` to my condition but it does nothing. I also tried str(file) and also no difference.

Comment: That doesn't sound like it has anything to do with the list comprehension. You're passing file names instead of full file paths to `isfile`.

Comment: `file` is always going to evaluate to `True` in a boolean context. Otherwise, you need to provide more information, in order to make this a reproducible example.

Comment: @a_guest Wut? That seems very misdirected…

Comment: @deceze What do you mean?

Comment: @a_guest Where is `file` being evaluated as a boolean here?

Comment: @deceze Third paragraph from the question: "What's more interesting is that if I replace the condition with something else, like `1 if file else 0`, the behaviour flipped." I was referring to that.

Comment: @a_guest Ah. That was less than clear…

Comment: Simple test: `files = os.listdir(path); print(files[0], os.path.isfile(files[0])`. What does that give you…?

Comment: there is a good shortcut for obtaining names of files inside directory: `all_files = next(os.walk(path))[2]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to pass the absolute path of the file to `isfile` function:

```
[1 if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, file)) else 0 for file in os.listdir(path)]
```

You can also achieve it without the `if`:

```
[int(os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, file))) for file in os.listdir(path)]
```

Comment: Wow so THAT was the problem...thanks for pointing that out, it is working now.

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without ternary operator:

```
[int(os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, file))) for file in os.listdir(path)]
```

or depending on what you plan to do with the resulting list:

```
[os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, file)) for file in os.listdir(path)]
```

I would always prefer the later